# Relating to Windows 10 Fresh Start

Tags: windows, windows-10, acer-aspire, intel-graphics

I wish to use the new feature on Windows 10 called "Fresh Start", then it says it will remove all applications and programs.
Currently i am using an Acer Desktop. Will removing apps such as Intel Graphics Driver and Intel Trusted Execution Engine together with manufacturer software such as AOP Framework and Acer Recovery Engine (This one is what i am most concerned) have any effects on my system.
I just want to know if these are safe to remove.

Thank You!

Edit: I should be able to reinstall the graphic interface, and what about the recovery engine, it is vital for recovery options, then why does it remove this.

Comment: Can't see relationship between "fresh start" and "removing Intel driver". Also, that driver is the one that allows you to have a graphic interface (so yes, theres an impact in your system) while the Intel TEE cannot be removed :)

Comment: @Alfabravo If you are not familiar with Fresh Start best to leave it to users who are familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

> I should be able to reinstall the graphic interface, and what about the recovery engine, it is vital for recovery options, then why does it remove this.

Acer software isn’t required for your system to function.  The reason it is being removed is because your using a feature designed to install a system state that has no OEM software installed.

> I just want to know if these are safe to remove.

They are safe to be removed.

> Will removing apps such as Intel Graphics Driver and Intel Trusted Execution Engine together with manufacturer software such as AOP Framework and Acer Recovery Engine (This one is what i am most concerned) have any effects on my system.

You should reinstall the Intel software after you reinstall Windows 10.  The Acer software is optional.